# Applying Vieta's Formulas generally

Tags: polynomials, roots

According to Wikipedia:
[image]
I am having trouble understanding what is omitted by the $\vdots$ .  How is the second statement reduced into the last?

Answer (score 4):

The first line contains the sum $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n$ of all roots.

The second line contains the sum of all products $x_ix_j$ of two *distinct* roots.

The third (omitted line) contains the sum of all products $x_ix_jx_k$ of three distinct roots.

And so on.

The list ($n$<sup>th</sup>) line contains the product of all $n$ roots.

Answer (score 1):

The left-hand-side of the $k$-th line is the sum of all algebraically distinct products of $k$ distinct terms of the sequence $x_1,...,x_n$.

For each product in the sum, there are ${\large{\binom{n}{k}}}$ ways of choosing the $k$ factors (up to algebraic equivalence), so we get ${\large{\binom{n}{k}}}$ summands.

It's usually read as:

> "The sum of the products of the roots, taken $k$ at a time."

In particular:

- For the first line ($k=1$), the left-hand-side
  $$x_1+\cdots + x_n$$
  has $n$ summands (since ${\large{\binom{n}{1}}}=n$), and is just the sum of the roots.$\\[12pt]$

  For the last line ($k=n$), the left-hand-side
  $$x_1\cdots x_n$$
  has only one summand (since ${\large{\binom{n}{n}}}=1$), and is just the product of the roots.

**Note:**

- When $k=1$, no actual multiplication is needed since each of the $n$ summands requires only one term.$\\[4pt]$

  When $k=n$, no actual addition is needed since there is only one summand.

As regards the right-hand side of the $k$-th line, it's just $(-1)^k\cdot{\large{\frac{a_{n-k}}{a_n}}}$. Note that the prefixed sign alternates, starting with a minus sign (i.e., for $k=1$, we have $(-1)^k=-1$).

As an example, letting $n=4$, we get
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1+x_2+x+x_3+x_4=-{\large{\frac{a_3}{a_4}}}\\[4pt]
x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4={\large{\frac{a_2}{a_4}}}\\[4pt]
x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_4=-{\large{\frac{a_1}{a_4}}}\\[4pt]
x_1x_2x_3x_4={\large{\frac{a_0}{a_4}}}\\[4pt]
\end{cases}
$$
To test the formula, and to get an idea as to why it holds, let's consider the second line of the above example . . .

By the Complete Factorization Theorem, we can express $P(x)$ as
$$P(x)=a_4(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)$$
In the expansion of $P$, you can verify that the $x^2$ coefficient, $a_2$, is equal to the sum of all products of the form $(a_4)(-x_i)(-x_j)$, where $1\le i < j\le 4$.

Thus, we get
$$a_2=a_4(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4)$$
which yields
$$x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4={\small{\frac{a_2}{a_4}}}$$